# Clicking upvote often clicks downvote on Android's browser

Tags: support, android

Several times when I clicked upvote on my Nexus One, downvote was clicked. This may be related to how Android's browswer renders the page.

Comment: Mandatory reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aBaX9GPSaQ

Answer (score 2):

"This may be related to how Android's browswer renders the page." – it's well known that the Android browser's assignment of clickable areas sometimes is a little weird on dynamic pages (e.g. if you insert something above a link, it takes the Android browser a few seconds to forget that this point is clickable).

In this case, however, I haven't seen anything like what you describe. I can vote just fine on the HTC Desire (which is very close to the Nexus One). FWIW, I tend to zoom in a bit when "clicking" on small links. After all, my finger tip is a little bit larger than a mouse cursor.

Comment: Voting also works OK for me on an HTC Wildfire