# Increase the distance between down vote and favorite buttons

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, mobile-web, bookmarks, design

Countless times on my phone (HTC Incredible, fwiw), I pressed down vote when I meant favorite. I've seen from others' comments that I'm not the only one with a fat thumb.

It'd be great if favorite can be above up vote, but that may be too big of a change to the most important part of the UI.

Therefore I'm only asking to move favorite down a few pixels.

A mockup of what I want:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65152/clicking-upvote-often-clicks-downvote-on-androids-browser

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66217/i-cant-add-a-favorite-in-the-stackexchange-beta-site-templates-from-the-androi

Comment: @Al Everett: yes it's the same problem as 65152, but that question didn't propose a solution.

Comment: Why don't you zoom in?

Comment: @KennyTM: first of all I shouldn't have to. And I did try, but sometimes it's still wrong, which is definitely my phone browser's fault.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: thanks for the edits. You can see I suck at thumbing.

Comment: @ItsNotALie - Please add [valid edit summary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16742) in future.

Comment: @It'sNotALie not sure that's what he meant. Having it aligned with tags is the same as having on top, too big a change. OP here just asked for "move favorite down a few pixels". As for favorites on the -54 questions people are just curious to see when it will get deleted I don't think those were meant to be downvotes in the first place. Last but not least, downvote is easily undoable, just click again and no harm done so don't think we really need to change anything here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It was just an idea, and also the downvote vs favourite things comes from my experience.